# Tkinter module not found on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>>
```

on the other hand...

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Mar 25 2011, 19:28:28) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

I checked synaptic, Tkinter is installed. Then I found this--

> If it fails with "No module named _tkinter", your Python configuration needs to be modified to include this module (which is an extension module implemented in C). Do not edit Modules/Setup (it is out of date). You may have to install Tcl and Tk (when using RPM, install the -devel RPMs as well) and/or edit the setup.py script to point to the right locations where Tcl/Tk is installed. If you install Tcl/Tk in the default locations, simply rerunning "make" should build the _tkinter extension.

I am guessing that tkinter is still associated with the old python in my pc. How do I change that so python3 can use tkinter?

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python3-tk" installs tkinter for Python3+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between tkinter and Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843596/difference-between-tkinter-and-tkinter)

Comment: "Then I found this" - that describes a different failure from what is actually seen in the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you mention synaptic I think you're on Ubuntu. You probably need to run [update-python-modules](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/update-python-modules.8.html) to update your Tkinter module for Python 3.

***EDIT***: Running update-python-modules

First, make sure you have `python-support` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-support
```

Then, run `update-python-modules` with the `-a` option to rebuild all the modules:

```
sudo update-python-modules -a
```

I cannot guarantee all your modules will build though, since there are some API changes between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python-support" leads to the following error "E: Package 'python-support' has no installation candidate"

Comment: I also had the same error as @jason `E: Package 'python-support' has no installation candidate` though I am running it from a docker (tensorflow image). Did anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: @CharlieParker On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I was able to fix this by `apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: For those of you with the `E: Package 'X' has no installation candidate`, you should run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: is there a way I can do this in a gitpod too? it doesnt let me use sudo nor lets me do without it

Comment: @AakankshaChoudhary You ___hav___ to use sudo for this, it's not possible without

Answer (score 327):

What worked for me in Ubuntu was actually just:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

For python 3.6:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

I didn't read anywhere, I simply tried it, as onteria_'s method didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: This package was indeed needed for me, but keep in mind that the name of `Tkinter` is now `tkinter` in Python3, so other answers are still relevant.

Comment: first command I get connection failed, the second one works fine though

Comment: I don't know what happened, `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` did not work for me (tkinter still not found), but installing `python3-tk` via synaptic did work. (Ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.6)

Comment: It still works. Well done

Comment: Perhaps quite late, but I checked the output of ``apt-cache policy python3*-tk`` , it gave me `python3-tk` as the viable one, the entries for 3.10-tk and 3.11-tk were blank. Installing `python3-tk` worked for me. (Ubuntu22.04, Python 3.10.6)

Answer (score 40):

The answer to your question is that `Tkinter` is renamed to `tkinter` in python3.

That is with lowercase t.

Comment: This is the actually correct answer based on what is actually shown in the original question. Everything else is making assumptions and solving a common problem, but not engaging with the issue actually shown in OP's actual attempt.

Answer (score 20):

In python 3 `T`kinter renamed `t`kinter

Comment: This is the answer to the question.

PS: If you run your script with a shebang, don't forget to use "#!/usr/bin/python3". On Ubuntu 12.04 for example default version of Python is 2.7.3 so "Tkinter" will work with "#!/usr/bin/python" but not with Python 3.

Comment: Second that this is the best and simplest answer to the question

Answer (score 20):

Use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

The following commands do not work:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tkinter
sudo apt-get install python3-Tkinter
pip3 install Tkinter
pip3 install tkinter
```

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 along with Python 3.6, then pip or pip3 won't help. You need to install `tkinter` using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: This merely seems to repeat multiple earlier answers from 2015-2017

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I tried to use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

It gave an error stating blt(>=2.4z-7) is not present and is not installable.

I went [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/14.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/blt_2.4z-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html) and manually installed it. (For Ubuntu 14.04)

Then I used apt again and it worked.

I concluded that python3.4 in Ubuntu didn't come with the .so file required to carry on installation. And blt was required to download it.

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
l = Label(root, text="Does it work")
l.pack()
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this looking for a fix for python 3.5.

In my case I was building python from source, here is what I did to help fix:

Add the tkinter headers with and rebuild python

```
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev
sudo make
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding solution for CentOs 7 (python 3.6.x)

```
yum install python36-tkinter
```

I had tried about every version possible, hopefully this helps out others.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the solution that I faced with `python 3.4` on `Fedora 21`. Hope this will help those facing a similar issue.

Any of these commands will install `tkinter`:

```
sudo yum install python3-tkinter
OR
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```

Answer (score 0):

requirement for tkinter:

python 3.6+

and go to shell
write the test code like :

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.mainloop()

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu 20.04 this works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

Comment: This solution has already been provided.

Comment: @AlexK but not for 20.04

Comment: If an existing answer is still valid for a newer release, there is no need to post another answer.