# Python: Tkinter & turtle

Tags: python, module, tkinter

Beginning programmer here. From How to Think Like a Computer scientist I got the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Screen()
alex.forward(150)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(150)
```

The program seems simple enough, Yet I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named turtle
```

After some internet research, I read that the turtle module can me found within the tkinter package. And so because I have two different python installations, Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3

I ran the following commands in Ubuntu terminal, in hopes to install the missing python modules:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
sudo apt-get install python3.2-tk
```

It got me nowhere. 
So how can I install the missing modules for both versions of python?

Thanks!

Comment: hey, were you able to fix this?

Comment: `alex = turtle.Screen()` -> `alex = turtle.Turtle()` -- doesn't fix your immediate problem but may spare you another if/when you do.

Answer (score 10):

On ubuntu 16.04,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

solved my problem, if this not work for you, see this question too
[Tkinter module not found on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

To setup Tkinter module in Python 2:

- Execute `sudo apt-get install python-tk` in the terminal.
- Use `import Tkinter` in your program.

For Python 3:

- Execute `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` in the terminal.
- Use `import tkinter` in your program.

Although Tkinter usually comes bundled up with Python 3, the above procedure will work incase the module is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `python3-tk` should solve your problem. I had the same problem on my ubuntu12.04 pc, solved it by installing `python3-tk`. This installs the `tkinter` module for python3 as you are executing your code on python3 only `(#!/usr/bin/env python3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an ldconfig to make sure the libraries are "known" to operating system.
Seemed to help when I was trying to get LED's to flash with PiFace.
Anyway, it wont hurt anything and is very quick. So worth a try IMHO. I think you need to be root (use sudo) to do that.

Answer (score -2):

For Fedora is dnf install python3-tkinter.x86_64

Answer (score -3):

Use `from turtle import Turtle` to import the turtle module,
instead of `import turtle`.