# NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined running turtle.Screen()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Here's my code:

```
window=turtle.Screen()
window.title("Pong")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(width=800,height=600)
window.tracer(0)
```

I get this error when I run the program:

```
 File "C:\Users\Aditya\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    window=turtle.Screen()
NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you imported the turtle module with an `import turtle` line?

Comment: sorry for such a silly question. I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to import turtle

```py
import turtle
window=turtle.Screen()
window.title("Pong")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(width=800,height=600)
window.tracer(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module before calling the sub-functions within it. In your case, you need the `turtle` module.

```
import turtle
window=turtle.Screen()
window.title("Pong")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(width=800,height=600)
window.tracer(0)
```

However, if you added the line: `import turtle`, and encounter the error below:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
import tkinter as TK 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

You may refer to this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286441/python-tkinter-turtle)

Answer (score -2):

Have you imported the Turtle module?
if you didn't, try this one:

```
from turtle import *
```

*Then the rest of your code*

Comment: This would not make the OP's code work as it imports everything in `turtle` into the current namespace.

Comment: Even if this did work, it's poor practice to pollute the `globals()` namespace with 100+ turtle functions, usually leading to large amounts of confusion and bugs.