# No module named 'Tkinter' in Jupyter Notebook.What's the reason behind this?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Error : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'**

Comment: it might be `import tkinter` if you're using a version with python3

Comment: Are you working with Python 3? In Python 3 it's `tkinter`, not `Tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

For python2 it is Tkinter

For python3 it is tkinter

jupyter notebook is mostly python3 so you may want to try

```
from tkinter import *
```

this question is similar to this question
[Difference between TKinter and tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843596/difference-between-tkinter-and-tkinter)

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated if you are using python 3 the module name has changed to tkinter from Tkinter, so using `import tkinter` should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
from Tkinter import *
win=Tk()
win.title('My First GUI')
win.mainloop()
```