# Installation of tkinter on python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, virtualenv, yum, fedora-21

I'm using Fedora 21. Installed the python3-tkinter package using `yum install python3-tkinter`. The package gets stored in the `/usr/lib64/python3.4` directory. Is there a way to use pip to install tkinter?

Have a virtualenv setup with python3. When I try to run my program within that virtualenv I get:

> ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'.

Does it make sense to copy the package directories from `/usr/lib64/python3.4` to the `site_packages` folder associated with the virtualenv?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu) the most straightforward way to do it is to sudo install instead of installing to usr. In order to do that with Fedora yum, you'll need to [install sudo first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55818/how-to-use-sudo-in-fedora). Does that work for you? Or do you have some restriction on installing with sudo?

Comment: I am the root user. So I don't have any restrictions on using sudo. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I was using python 3.3.2 interpreter. Turns out the default packages installed when running the command     yum install python3-tkinter are set to work with python 3.4.1 interpreter. Configuring my virtualenv to use the python 3.4.1 interpreter proved to be the solution as the python interpreter was then able to find the required libraries in it's path.