# How to use ffmpeg read realtime microphone audio volume?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have Google this proplem, Here is a simliar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138031/how-to-read-realtime-microphone-audio-volume-in-python-and-ffmpeg-or-similar)

But when i exectue following command

```
val command = arrayOf("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg",
    "-f", "avfoundation",
    "-i", ":2",
    "-t", "5",
    "-ar", "11025",
    "-ac", "1",
    "-acodec","aac", "-")
```

I got this error `Unknown input format: 'avfoundation'`
Who has ideas for this problem?

PS: My platform is android, i am using `android-ffmpeg lib`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running `ffmpeg` on Android, but [avfoundation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation) is only supported by Apple devices.

Comment: yes, i am running ffmpeg on Android, so Do you know what kind of commands i should use?

Comment: @Cyrus I don't know anything about Android, but perhaps it supports ALSA. See [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#alsa) and [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA).

Comment: You can type `ffmpeg -devices` to list the available devices (regardless of the platform where you're running it). However, I just tried to run the command from Android and only got back the `lavfi`, being the `Libavfilter` input virtual device. It seems that `ffmpeg` doesn't get the internal devices on Android (but I might be wrong)