# Can we Stream Live Audio from Android phone using FFmpeg?

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffmpegkit

Im using [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) package to Stream data to the RTSP server in Flutter.

**IOS : Working**

**Android : Its not working**

**Command Used :**

```
'ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" -acodec aac -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp "$Url"'
```

When i ran a "`ffmpeg -devices`" command on android, it returns follwing response, through which i got to know android doesn't support avfoundation but android has `android_camera`,
Does this `android_camera` support audio too?

**Command : 'ffmpeg -devices'**

**Response :**

```
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
I/flutter (10620): logs:Devices:
I/flutter (10620):  D. = Demuxing supported
I/flutter (10620):  .E = Muxing supported
I/flutter (10620):  --
I/flutter (10620): logs: D  android_camera   
I/flutter (10620): logs: D  lavfi            
I/flutter (10620): logs: DE video4linux2,v4l2
```

**Commands which I tried in Android**

```
FFmpegKit.execute('-y -f android_camera -i 0:1 -r 30 -c:a aac -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp "$Url"');

FFmpegKit.execute('-y -f android_camera -i 0:1 -r 30 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "/storage/emulated/0/Download/androidvideo.mp3"');

FFmpegKit.execute('-y -f android_camera -i 0:0 -r 30 -c:a wavpack -b:a 64k "/storage/emulated/0/Download/androidvideo.wav"');
```

**This command records video but no audio in it.**

```
FFmpegKit.execute('-video_size hd720 -f android_camera -camera_index 1 -i anything -r 10 -t 00:00:15 "$dir/androidvideo.mp4”');
```

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643602/ffmpeg-command-to-capture-audio-from-android-mobile

Answer (score 2):

the **android_camera** input device in FFmpeg for Android does not support audio capture. It only captures video from the Android camera but does not capture audio from the device's microphone.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the following sources, ffmpeg for Android supports only video capturing from the camera using the `android_camera` device:

- [How to use ffmpeg read realtime microphone audio volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194826/how-to-use-ffmpeg-read-realtime-microphone-audio-volume)
- https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/issues/153

Though on iOS the `avfoundation` supports video and audio.

As an option, the audio could be recorded by the native means, `MediaRecorder` or `AAudio / OpenSL ES` via `JNI` for example,
and then mixed with the video recorded from the camera.

The ffmpeg would take audio data from an audio buffer (a temp file as a simplest option or a in-memory buffer, but this would need to be investigated further for how to configure it in the call string).