# How to get current system volume with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, system, volume

[Image of What I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1leTc.png)

I want to get the current system volume, not the one that is set by the user, but the one that is actively happening, for example if I am speaking to someone in a discord chat, and he's talking quietly it will show me 10%, but if he's talking loudly, it will jump to 80. I searched everywhere but all I get is using the microphone, and I want the sounds from the system, what can I do to get it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138031/how-to-read-realtime-microphone-audio-volume-in-python-and-ffmpeg-or-similar

Comment: @JairusMartin this, but with nodeJS...

Comment: Nodejs can run scripts, i.e. have it run a python script as a command.

Comment: In node you can run command line commands, from command-line it should not be a problem to get real time audio.

Comment: @Alex and how would you do that?

Comment: @neryushi you are on windows right? 
I can not test it but to pass commands you can do the following `var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('ls -al', function (error, stdOut, stdErr) {
console.log(stdOut)
});`
Would print in an unix enviroment the list of files in the  directory
In Linux you could do now something like this instead of ls-al you can write `awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)
?` Referencing this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89571/how-to-get-volume-level-from-the-command-line

Comment: For Windows I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms678715(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN or here is a Command Line Tool : https://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-edl/files/current_system_volume_vista_plus_flush.exe/download 

But maybe if this python script is exactly what you need it would be the best as @JairusMartin mentioned to run that python script in your node enviroment and get the output from that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the package [win-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-audio):

```
const audio = require('win-audio');
 
// speaker volume
const speaker = audio.speaker;
// get the current volume percentage
var currentVolume = speaker.get();

// microphone volume
const microphone = audio.mic;
```

Comment: This is not what the question asked for, I asked for how to get the actual volume that is being played by your computer. The green from the photo