# Is tkinter included with python3 debian package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter

From my understanding, tkinter is built in to python. However, when i tried to run the following code

```
from turtle import *
```

I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "myturtle.py", line 1, in 
>       from turtle import *
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 107, in 
>       import tkinter as TK
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

I solved this by doing

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

But why did I have to do this? I thought tkinter would come with my python3 installation. I installed it with the apt command.

I'm also new to package management and trying to learn. I am using Ubuntu which I think uses the Debian package manager. Does it have to do with that?

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu

Comment: @JoelD'Souza The link that you provided does not explain why Tkinter is not included. In fact, despite being a library module and the Wikipedia claim that it comes with Python on all major platforms, the number of questions like "How do I install tkinter?" suggests that very often it is not a part of the default installation. The question "why" remains open.