# install tkinter for python 3.7.3 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

When I import tinker in python 3.7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
>>> import tkinter
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Then I install tk using both of the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

It didn't work.

I also did all the things in [Tkinter module not found on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu), still didn't work.
I noticed that when I do:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk
```

It says:

```
Note, selecting 'python3-tk' instead of 'python3.7-tk'
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04).
```

Is tk automatically installed under python 3.6.9? How can I fix this?

I also saw a solution from https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter:

> If it fails with "No module named _tkinter", your Python configuration needs to be modified to include this module (which is an extension module implemented in C). Do **not** edit Modules/Setup (it is out of date). You may have to install Tcl and Tk (when using RPM, install the -devel RPMs as well) and/or edit the setup.py script to point to the right locations where Tcl/Tk is installed. If you install Tcl/Tk in the default locations, simply rerunning "make" should build the _tkinter extension.

Could someone explain to do how to do the steps mentioned in this paragraph?

Comment: Pick one from: [`"No module named '_tkinter'"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+%22No+module+named+%27_tkinter%27%22)

Comment: Did you build Python 3.7 yourself?

Comment: I think I just installed it using `sudo apt install python3.7`

Comment: I can import tkinter in python 3.6.9. And I just can't install it to 3.7.3. What should I do?

Comment: Normally, using `apt-get install python3.7` should install files to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib`.  But your error message shows that the files are installed to `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`.  It looks like it is installed from source.  Try to reinstall `python3.7` and `python3-tk`.  `python3-tk` includes libraries for version 3.6 to 3.8.  And you can execute `dpkg-query -L python3-tk` to show installed files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think the problem is that the newest version of tkinter for Ubuntu 18.04 is "python3-tk_3.6.9-1~18.04_i386.deb". Now I found that tk for python3.7.3 is available for other systems(e.g. python3-tk_3.7.3-1_amd64.deb). Can I download and use these ones on my system?

Comment: Actually `python3-tk` includes tkinter for Python 3.6 to 3.8.  You can list files installed by executing `dpkg-query -L python3-tk`.

Answer (score 0):

**acw1668**: Thanks this helped me a lot. I'm using Python 3.8. Using your method was able find where tkinter for Python 3.8 was install (/usr/lib/python3.8/). So i copied the files to (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/) which is where Python is installed on my computer. Now it'e working.