# Python Turtle error in python main modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-turtle

File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 107, in 
import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Error occurring in linux python modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter module not found on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Just asked a couple of days ago: [Turtle module: import tkinter as TK ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724978/turtle-module-import-tkinter-as-tk-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tkinte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I found that this worked for UBUNTU for me (same for debian other flavours)

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk
```

since I have python 3.10 you would need to use your version.

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143036/1422486

Answer (score 0):

In Arch, Tk is available in the Arch repository.
The following fixed it for me on Manjaro. Just type on the terminal:

```bash
pacman -S tk
```

If you are using one of Debian flavours, Ubuntu, Mint etc...

```bash
apt-get install tk
```